# Public Access Token for Facebook, Permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to the Facebook Graph API!

I want to display the 5 latest news feed items from my public Facebook page. I understand you can do that through https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed/?limit=5, but it requires an access token, however, https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola doesn't.

When these access tokens are generated through Facebook's Graph API Explorer, what permissions are given for the token? Just the information already displayed in the above link?

So would it be safe to use the access token via cURL's PHP? I only need read access. Would it be insecure to display the access token in the source code? I'm confused as to why the latter link doesn't need an access token while the /feed/ does, even though it's a public facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

when you use your app in a website there is a parameter that defines how much access you have from the user, u can set up params like, email, photo_stream, friend_stream, etc. when the user accepts the conditions, the generated AUTH TOKEN has permisions from that scope.

Comment: I just need read data though for my own public FB page.. The whole permissions thing seems a bit overkill.

Comment: to access any private information from any user, even yourself, you need permision, and thats done through an auth token.